# How to make a sum of total for each id

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal report 7

I want to view the table 1 and sum of table2

table1

```
id name

001 raja
002 vijay
003 suresh
....
```

table2

```
id value

001 100
001 200
001 150
002 200
003 150
003 200
...
```

I want to display all the rows from table1 and sum(values) from table2.  How to do this 
in crystal report

Expected Output

```
id name value

001 raja 450
002 vijay 200
003 suresh 350
................
           1000 (sum of value)
```

Note: I add the table field directly to the report, i am not added store procedure or views or query in the report.

How to do this.

Need Crystal report help

Comment: this can be achived from database end very easily

Comment: @Asif, I know how to do this in sql query but in crystal report how...? i am not using any query in the report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will work for you

1) Add a Group in your crystal report i.e. by Name

[image]

2) Add a running total

[image]

[image]

3) your report will be as follow

[image]

4) Your output will be

[image]

Comment: I have add a new image after 2) Add a running total which is describing how to make a running total.

Comment: Go into field explorer then right click on running total then give a name to your formula and then add Table_2.Value in field to summarize and check the on change of group and select Group #1 Table_1.Name click ok and then drag it on to the report. Please follow the screen shots you will get your desired results.

Comment: can you right click on report and then click insert and then click on running total. check this link http://victoriayudin.com/2009/11/25/running-totals-in-crystal-reports/

Comment: have u added 1000 (sum of value) in your question....? which part you have updated..

Comment: I updated my qustion 1000 (Sum of value). plz check what exactly i need. I create a name for running total as "Close", then i followed your advised.  Then i added close field running total  in group field name as "Clo", it is displaying correctly, now i want to show a sum of running total "Clo" field, when i add a sum of (summary of clo) field, it is showing as running total cannot able to add a sum"  message..

Comment: add another running total and select field Table_2.value and place it at the end of report.

Answer (score 0):

Join Table 1 and Table 2 on ID.
Add the fields ID, Name, and Value to your report.
Group the report on ID and Insert a Summary field (SUM) on VALUE to the Group Header.
Add Name to the Group Header.
Add a Grand Total (Report Footer) on Value.
Hide or Supress the Details band.

This will give you the same as you desire, but without the necessity of Running Totals and resets.