# Calculate Sum In Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working on Crystal report 2010 and I have Header group for each Bill detail.
It's working fine but how To Calculate sum for each group in Crystal Report?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a sum of total for each id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186444/how-to-make-a-sum-of-total-for-each-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click on Field which u want to sum,
And insert Summary ,
Then in summary Loaction Field , Select the Group
THus u can solve ur problem